# Riemann hypothesis cannot be proved to be unprovable?

Tags: incompleteness, riemann-hypothesis

I'm coming off the numberphile video: https://youtu.be/O4ndIDcDSGc

In the very end, they say that 'Proving that Riemann hypothesis is unprovable would be a proof of the truth of Riemann hypothesis'

The reasoning given is: Riemann hypothesis cannot be both unprovable and false. Because if it is false, then it is provably false because a computer could find the counter example to prove it false.

But this all means that we cannot prove that Riemann Hypothesis is unprovable because proving so would prove the non-existence of any counter-example and hence would prove Riemann Hypothesis itself.

P.S.  I'm not sure if I agree with their reasoning. 'Provability' is supposed to be 'provability from the axioms', right? If we just found a counter-example in the wild, then yeah, we've proven it to be false but we haven't done so from the axioms. I think it might be possible for a statement to be provable by counter-examples but unprovable by axioms, so that if we have proved that Riemann Hypothesis is unprovable from our axioms, we still haven't proved that we can't find a counter-example. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: In general proving something is unprovable doesn't prove anything else. But for the RH, if there is an off-line zero then there is an algorithm proving it (the one enumerating the zeros). Ie. (assuming arithmetic is consistent) the truth/falsity of the RH can be unprovable only if there are no off-line zeros. This is a common feature of sentences of the form "this Turing machine never halts".

Comment: @reuns But that's a contradiction because we've proved it by proving it is unprovable. So it's provable as well as unprovable. That means our assumption that 'there is a proof of its uprovability'  must be wrong.

Comment: We'll settle in a theory larger than PA to prove that the RH is **unprovable in PA** and that it implies that the RH is true. A contradiction is when in a single theory you get A and $\lnot $ A. Unprovable in PA means that the program enumerating the theorems of PA searching for a (dis)proof of the RH will never halt.

Comment: @reuns I'm not sure I understand that. What could be the larger theory? Would we have to include Riemann Hypothesis (or its equivalent) as an axiom in the larger theory?

Comment: @reuns Because if PA can neither prove nor disprove RH, but our larger theory (with additional axioms) can, then assuming the additional axioms has to be the equivalent of assuming RH itself. But then such a proof of RH shouldn't count because we are already assuming RH.

Comment: what about if you think this way - if RH is not provable within PA say, then it cannot be false within PA; in particular no non-trivial zero can have real part outside the critical line, so all the usual approximation and bounding results that follow from the fact that RH is "true" hold since all depend precisely on the fact that no non-trivial zeroes are outside the critical line

Comment: @RyderRude It is possible that a statement cannot be proven in PA, but in ZFC,  Goodstein's theorem being the most famous example. Of course, WITHIN PA we cannot prove that RH is inpedendent of PA (neither true nor false) because this would lead to a contradiction. But ZFC might be strong enough to show that there is an interpretation in PA with respect to which RH is false and also one with respect to which RH is true. In this case , PA could not prove RH because this is only possible for statements that are universally true (true with respect to every interpretation)

Comment: @RyderRude Adding RH as an axiom would allow to "prove" RH, but this is of course useless. What is meant here that we have to use a stronger theory. It could also be that RH is indpendent of ZFC, but an even stronger theory can prove it. What we can surely say : In the (unlikely) case that RH is false, PA surely can disprove it. If it is however true, a proof might nevertheless not exist (perhaps not even in ZFC), assuming that ZFC is true which we of course must assume.

Comment: Note that in the case of Goldbach's conjecture, we have a similar situation, but in the case of the Collatz conjecture it is even worse. If there is a number with diverging trajectory, we cannot be sure that this can be proven.

Comment: A last comment : "unprovable" is the wrong formulation for this situation. If RH is false, it is also "unprovable". So the implication "unprovable $\implies$ true" is false.

Comment: Correction : "ZFC is true" must be replaced by "ZFC is consistent". Sorry for this mistake.

Comment: "If we just found a counter-example in the wild, then yeah, we've proven it to be false but we haven't done so from the axioms." As long as we can *after the fact* write up the definition and verification of that counterexample in our axiomatic framework, then **yes**, that is a proof from the axioms. It doesn't matter where the idea came from, just that it can ultimately be captured within that framework.

Comment: Meanwhile, since [RH is ZFC-equivalent to a $\Pi_1$ statement](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31846/is-the-riemann-hypothesis-equivalent-to-a-pi-1-sentence) and ZFC is ZFC-provably $\Sigma_1$-complete (basically, ZFC can verify all simple arithmetical calculations), it follows that we can prove in ZFC the sentence "If ZFC doesn't disprove RH, then RH is true." And ZFC is *massive* overkill here (as usual).

Comment: The shift to $\Pi_1$ statements **is** important here: for an arbitrary statement of the form "Every real number has property $P$," even if $P$ is easily checkable it could be the case that $P$ is false but the only counterexamples to $P$ are too complicated to even define in the axiomatic framework. Shifting to arithmetic removes this issue, since every natural number is expressible in our language. In general, if $P$ is a reasonably-simple (= computable) property of natural numbers, then the sentence $\forall x P(x)$ is false iff it is ZFC-disprovable *(and ZFC is, again, massive overkill)*.